# Drupal redirect - subdomain to domain

Tags: html, redirect, dns, drupal-7, subdomain

I Have a drupal 7 website with a plain domain: example.com .

I have another server with apache2 for creating static webpages and hotsites in a subdomain: content.example.com .

Would be ever possible to redirect specific pages from my subdomain, for example: content.example.com/2014/special to my root domain , like example.com/special ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use an .htaccess file to re-write the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using .htaccess files. Ex:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^content\.example\.com/2014/special$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/special [R=301,L]
```

Haven't tested, but pretty sure that works. Correct me if I am wrong.

make a file called .htaccess (make sure it is not .htaccess.txt), and put it in the directory of the page you want to redirect.